# Can internet access be provided only once?

Tags: networking, wireless-router

Using a tp-link tl-wr740n router can internet access be provided only once to a particular device? When that device tries to connect next or even more times the connection should not be established. Only the adminstrator of the router should be able to provide connection to that device for the second or later times. This should be performed without changing router password.

Is this possible?? if yes then how?

Comment: Unless manual solutions (MAC filtering, etc.) are an option, than I'd go with Daniel's idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like what you really want is a so-called [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). The manufacturers firmware usually doesn't support this on consumer-grade devices. You might be in luck though, depending in your device's revision, [OpenWrt actually supports it](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr740n). There are [various solutions](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.overview#captive.portal.software.available.in.the.openwrt.repository) available for OpenWrt.

You could also create something like this yourself, but reinventing the wheel is generally considered bad practice. :)

Comment: Does openwrt do the same job what mac filtering do?

Answer (score -1):

How do you want to define the administrator without defining a password. How could the router make a difference between a user and an administrator? Just the username ? Is that safe ? 
I myself  got a TP-LINK router and there is a default user called = admin and password admin and if you log on you can set up your router the way you want to you might be able to set up another account but the differences may differ according your firmware but if am not mistaken there has to be a password set up for the account in order to log in .

Hope this answers your question .

Comment: That's indeed pretty safe -- admin admin..

Comment: You misunderstood him.
He said that only the administrator of the router would be able to give a second access for that specific device.